# Ubuntu black screen after reboot or shutdown (16.04 LTS)

Tags: dual-boot, amd-graphics

So I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on my Laptop:
Dell Inspiron 3521 (Intel Core i3 3227u - Intel HD 4000 and AMD Radeon HD 7670m).

The Laptop runs fine on all the other Operating Systems except Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

I`ve tried:

- Windows 7
- Windows 8
- Windows 8.1
- Linux Mint 17
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Ubuntu 15.04
- Ubuntu 15.10

And it works on all of them.

But it does not work on anything after Ubuntu 15.10

What I have tried to solve the problem:

1. Reinstalled Ubuntu
2. Upgraded BIOS/ Downgraded BIOS (Screen Displays the First time. Works until Ubuntu 16 is shutdown or rebooted.)
3. Tried Clearing CMOS (Works the First time after that)

Please Don't link my question to :[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've tried it all.
Also, it Works fine if `nomodeset` is always used. 
But then my Intel GPU is never Used and the processor get damn hot.

Comment: are you using third party drivers? ubuntu kernels newer than 4.3 require signed drivers if secure boot is set

Comment: Secure Boot is disabled. And I am Using Default Ubuntu Drivers.